# Rasperry Pi alternative with USB 3.0, Ethernet port, and casing?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I am looking for Raspberry PI 3 alternative board which would give me:

1. USB 3.0 port. Single is enough.
2. Ethernet port.
3. Casing. (Built-in / bought separately)

Orange PI 3 is perfect for my needs except that company does not or no longer produces casing. But casing is very important for my needs.

Please advice me any alternative board. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't the Pi 4 do it? It has 2x USB 3.0 and more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I looked around the web, and I found these options:

## Pine64

The [Rock64](https://www.pine64.org/?page_id=7147) or the [RockPro64](https://www.pine64.org/?page_id=61454) are good options.

As for today, these are the only ones with USB 3.0 from Pine64.

## Odroid

You could also choose to buy a Odroid.

I recommend checking the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODROID#Specifications) seeing what model suits the best your needs. You can find without any problem a case on amazon.